# EditorFor on nullable DateTime - "Nullable object must have a value."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am attempting to display a form that allows a user to input a new assignment for a person.  I'm using a DateTime.cshtml EditorTemplate to handle DateTime values for the assignment.  The non-nullable DateTime works fine.  The nullable DateTime causes an "InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value."

I have a simple viewmodel that looks like this:

AssignmentViewModel.cs:

```
public Person Person { get; set; }
public Assignment NewAssignment { get; set; }
```

Assignment.cs contains:

```
public DateTime AssignmentStartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? AssignmentEndDate { get; set; }
```

My AssignmentController Create() method looks like:

```
public ViewResult Create(int personId)
{
    Person person = personRepository.GetPersonById(personId);
    var newAssignment = new AssignmentViewModel { Person = person, NewAssignment = new Assignment() };
    return View(newAssignment);
}
```

My Create.cshtml view looks like this:

```
@model AssignmentViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Assignment"))
{
    @Html.Hidden("NewAssignment.PersonId", Model.Person.PersonId)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.NewAssignment.AssignmentStartDate):
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.NewAssignment.AssignmentStartDate.Date, new { cssClass = "datePicker" })
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.NewAssignment.AssignmentEndDate):
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.NewAssignment.AssignmentEndDate.Value.Date, new { cssClass = "datePicker" })
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send />
}
```

My DateTime.cshtml EditorTemplate looks like:

```
@model DateTime?

@{
    String modelValue = "";
    if (Model.HasValue)
    {
        if (Model.Value != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            modelValue = Model.Value.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
}

@Html.TextBox("", modelValue, new { @class = "datePicker" })
```

When I attempt to load the Create view, I get the exception mentioned above on the line "@Html.EditorFor(x => x.NewAssignment.AssignmentEndDate.Value)".

You may be wondering why I'm passing in AssignmentEndDate.Value.Date instead of just passing in AssignmentEndDate; the reason is because I'm trying to get to the point where I'm splitting DateTime into Date and a TimeOfDay field and recombine them with a DateTimeModelBinder.  I am using a similar technique to the one [shown here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx) and [here](http://devblog.lundy.us/2010/09/28/date-time-picker-asp-net-mvc-jquery-part-1/).

I -can- bypass the error, by changing my controller Create() method to instantiate the ViewModel with AssignmentEndDate set to DateTime.MinValue, but this seems completely wrong for a nullable DateTime:

```
var newAssignment = new AssignmentViewModel 
                        { 
                            Person = person, 
                            NewAssignment = new Assignment { AssignmentEndDate = DateTime.MinValue } 
                        };
```

Something strange happens after I "bypass" the error by supplying a value for the nullable DateTime; the un-required nullable DateTime property (AssignmentEndDate.Date) fails client side validation.  Trying to submit the form highlights the field in red.

How can I handle this correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to retrieve the `AssignmentEndDate.Value.Date`, but `AssignmentEndDate` is `null`, which results in this error.

Since your editor template accepts a `DateTime?`, you should just pass along the `AssignmentEndDate`.  In other words, remove the `.Value.Date` from the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.NewAssignment.AssignmentEndDate, new { cssClass = "datePicker" })
```

Since your editor template is using `ToShortDateString()`, there's no need to "truncate" the time from the date at all.

### Update

Regarding your desire to have separate "Date" and "Time" editors:

You can do this 2 ways.

1 - Your current `DateTime?` editor renders a field for the `Model.Value.Date`, so you could simply extend this to also render a field for the `Model.Value.TimeOfDay`.  Example:

```
@{
  DateTime? modelDate = (Model == null) ? (DateTime?)null : Model.Value.Date;
  TimeSpan? modelTime = (Model == null) ? (TimeSpan?)null : Model.Value.TimeOfDay;
}
@Html.TextBox(..., modelDate, new{@class="datePicker"})
@Html.TextBox(..., modelTime, new{@class="timePicker"})
```

2 - You could split the above functionality into 2 separate editors, "DateOnly" and "TimeOnly". Then, update your view to call both editors:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.NewAssignment.AssignmentEndDate, "DateOnly")
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.NewAssignment.AssignmentEndDate, "TimeOnly")
```

The choice is up to you, and whether you want to keep the Date and Time parts separate or together, but this is how I'd go about solving this problem.

Comment: Hi Scott, I actually already tried that first fix.  I get "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

The second suggestion would address this immediate error, but doesn't allow me to have two fields for Date and Time; see text in my question that starts, "You may be wondering...".

Comment: The first part makes sense ... that's a MVC thing, which doesn't support the null-check logic.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: If you want 2 separate fields for Date and Time, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't see anything in your answer about using separate fields for the date and time components of a DateTime property?  Just removing .Value.Date won't work.  I'm giving up on this for now, I'll accept your answer because it answered the main question, but I can't find a solution that addresses all of issues I'm having. :|

Comment: It may be from a WPF background but combining/splitting data I feel belongs in a ViewModel, I'd suggest adding an "AssignmentViewModel" which mirrors assignment.cs but contains 2 `DateTime`s (for start/end date) and 2 `TimeSpan`s (for start/end time). I chose to inherit my ViewModels from an IViewModel<T> interface, with a `public T CreateModel();` function where I'd put the logic `return new Assignment(){ AssignmentStartDate=StartDate.Date.Add( StartTime ), AssignmentEndDate=EndDate.Date.Add( EndTime ) };`

Answer (score 2):

create a DateTime.cshtml in your Shared/DisplayTemplate folder

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>
@(Model != null ? string.Format(ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString ?? "{0:d}", Model) : string.Empty)
```

this supports metadata from datannotations to be used if found.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: GetValueOrDefault treats it as a DateTime and therefore the required Field validators are getting attached, because the original expression is for a datetime not a nullable datetime.

### Therefore the solution below doesn't work.

Like the asker, I also used the DateTimeModelBinder from here: 
[Here's the Link](http://devblog.lundy.us/2010/09/28/date-time-picker-asp-net-mvc-jquery-part-1/)

This is how I solved a similar situation:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.NewAssignment.AssignmentEndDate.GetValueOrDefault().Date)
```

And this is what my DateTime EditorTemplate looks like:

```
@model DateTime

@Html.TextBox("", Model != default(DateTime) ? Model.ToShortDateString() : String.Empty, new { @class = "datepicker", @maxlength = "10" })
```