# TextBoxFor Helper conditional value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I'm trying to populate a textbox with a `DateTime` value from a database. If the `DateTime` value is null (ie. 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM), I want the textbox to display an **empty string** to the user instead.

Currently, it still shows the value for a null date (ie. "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM").

Please see my code snippet below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstBillingDate, new { @value = (Model.FirstBillingDate >= Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01") ? Model.FirstBillingDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : ""), @class = "form-control datepicker", @id = "first-billing-date" })
```

Comment: Isn't working meaning it shows the date?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi The problem is that my textbox is not displaying an empty string (ie. "") if the `DateTime` is null.

Comment: @SamGhatak It shows "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" which is the corresponding value for a null `DateTime`. If I have a null `DateTime` in my database, I would like for it to display an empty string and not "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM".

Comment: If `FirstBillingDate` is DateTime? try solution from this [SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580780/editorfor-on-nullable-datetime-nullable-object-must-have-a-value).

Comment: If the value is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` then its **not** `null` its a valid date!. Change your property to be `DateTime?` (nullable) so that it is stored in the database as `null` and then use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstBillingDate)` And **never** set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstBillingDate, new { Value = (Model.FirstBillingDate >= Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01") ? Model.FirstBillingDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : ""), @class = "form-control datepicker", @id = "first-billing-date" })
```

Comment: I had that previously but upon checking the HTML that was rendered, there are duplicate `value` attributes for the textbox. I want to avoid this if possible. **Edit**: Here is what's generated: <input Value="" class="form-control datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field FirstBillingDate must be a date." data-val-required="The FirstBillingDate field is required." id="first-billing-date" name="FirstBillingDate" type="text" value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" />. Notice the **Value=""** at the beginning of the tag and **value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"** at the end.

Comment: Ok, sorry...this one worked for me...didn't cross check it though..let me try something else too

Comment: Will it be better to wrap a new `string` property around `FirstBillingDate` ? 

`public string FirstBillingDateForView{
    get{
         return (FirstBillingDate >= Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01") ? FirstBillingDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : "");
    }
    set{
         FirstBillingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
    }
}`